# getData() is not working since migration to kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, uri

I am new to kotlin. I wrote this code that will get image from image picker.
But I am getting error on line:`val filePath: Uri = attr.data.getData()`
error: Unresolved reference. Is there any change in kotlin because this code was working properly in java (Means I migrated to kotlin)

And another error on  `imageStore(bitmap)` error: smart cast to bitmap is impossible.

I've searched for documentation but couldn't solve this 2 problems .

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        val filePath: Uri = attr.data.getData()

        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(filePath)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            imageStore(bitmap)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat trace where the issue exists

Comment: @Quicklearner I haven't run the code. The error is coming in IDE (red-lines under text and tool tip i.e. suggestions (context actions))

Comment: @techfangirl if my answer has resolved all your issues please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_local_nobody said "the migration tool isn't perfect", I learned the basics of kotlin and found that the following code works fine for me.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val filePath = data.data
        try {
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(filePath!!)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            imageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            imageStore(bitmap)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I am getting error on line:val filePath: Uri = attr.data.getData() error: Unresolved reference

Well, this means the compiler can't understand what you're referring to. Is it correct to say this ?

Well, considering you don't have any object named `attr` it would seem that the compiler is correct.

this means you should remove the `attr` part, something like:

```
val filePath: Uri = data?.getData() ?: return
```

The return here will stop executing the rest of the method if the data from the intent is null

To resolve your second problem, you'll need something like this :

```
bitmap?.let { bitmapInstance ->
   imageStore(bitmapInstance)  
 }
```

What does this do ?

Well, it gives you thread safe access to your bitmap object and also ensures that the instance isn't null.

Comment: As I mentioned I coded this in java few months ago and now I just use 'Migrate to kotlin' feature of android studio. The code (before migration) works correctly without error

Comment: yes, the migration tool isn't perfect, i'm trying to teach you how to approach these problems in future by explaining what `Unresolved reference` means @techfangirl :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `val filePath: Uri = attr.data.getData()` with

```
 val filePath: Uri = data!!.getData()!!
```

**Updated code**

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        val filePath: Uri = data!!.getData()!!

        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(filePath)
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            imageStore(bitmap)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch: Required Uri